# How to open vsdx file?

Tags: visio

I have a .VSDX extension file. And I am not getting the tool to open it.

I have tried Visio Viewer (Google Chrome extension). But it's not showing in the chrome toolbar.

Can any one suggest online website or tool to open it?

Comment: no body talks about the [Visio Viewer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Visio-Viewer-to-view-or-print-Visio-drawings-08CCE46E-D5F2-460A-86C3-679C32DCA94A) ?

Comment: This was improperly closed.  The first word of the question clearly asks "How", not what is the best, thus this is not an opinion/endless discussion.  Furthermore, lots of people will want to know the answer to this question (especially for other platforms).

Answer (score 35):

Go to [diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/?splash=0) and drag and drop the .vsdx file into the editor

If company policy forbids the use of such a site, there's a [desktop version](https://get.diagrams.net).

If you wanted to make a site available internally that views .vsdx files without installing the desktop version on every machine, serve the [source code](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio) from a web server. The operation is client-side, you don't need any back-end running.

Comment: If your company policy forbids the user of diagrams.net, then the desktop app itself is probably the best to avoid. The last time I checked the desktop app sent the entire vsdx file to diagrams.net for conversion. [source](https://github.com/jgraph/www.diagrams.net-source/blob/860d773844b8a3c9dac2d751af262efa45d360ef/_posts/2200-03-11-data-governance-drawio.md)

Comment: @robbert229 That article does not apply to the desktop version. The desktop version never sends data externally. The CSP applied to the web view prevents any possible data egress.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install Microsoft Visio 2010 Service Pack 2 (SP2) or Microsoft Visio 2013 Viewer.

Comment: ,is there any online website that can open it ?

Comment: No, only someone like [this](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/tour/visio_viewer), but is not free.

Comment: According to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35811 MS Visio 2013 Viewer supports only Win7, Win8 and IE8,9,10.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm importing from VisualStudio 2013 (.VSDX) works very well, only some issue with lines but easy to correct.

So far, I think Lucidchart is an interesting tool (export to pdf and png, for example, are very useful)

You can also use open it using [LibreOffice Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) (tested on 4.3.1.2). It's completely free and from here you can create pdf or export to PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Just Store it on O365 or on OneDrive you will be able to view it (even from iOS using free Visio Viewer).
If you want to view and modify you need Visio Plan P1 (5$/Month). Dont forget you will also be able to create new diagram directly from you browser.

Answer (score 1):

The *.vsdx* is a new Microsoft Visio file format introduced in Visio 2013. In order to open it you should have supported Visio Installation. You can also open *.vsdx* file using some online tools like [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com). Signup for the trial account, in the dashboard go to *File -> Import Diagram -> Visio File*. After importing you can also edit a diagram as per your need and can then again export it to Visio File.